# Is Mootools' $$ a synonym of jQuery's $?

Tags: mootools

I consider jQuery's `$` function very handy. I know MooTools returns an Elements instance, but *as a selector* are there specific differences? Can you select whatever node on the Dom tree?

Comment: Yes, its basically the same. MooTools `document.getElements()` would be maybe a closer match but for the purpose of selecting nodes in the DOM tree they both do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mootools started with both functions `$` and `$$`, then they removed the first one (they keep an alias, so you can also use `$`) in favor of `document.id`; `$$` can be used exactly as the `jQuery` version. The main difference between the jQuery `$` and the Mootools `$$` is that the jQuery version will query the DOM using `document.querySelector`, while the Mootools version will query the DOM and instances of Mootools classes. To query classes, the class must have the method `toElement` implemented, and the method must return a reference to the DOM element.

You can learn more on [elements and element selection](https://mootools.net/core/docs/1.6.0/Element/Element), the [dollar](https://mootools.net/core/docs/1.6.0/Element/Element#Window:dollar) and [dollars](https://mootools.net/core/docs/1.6.0/Element/Element#Window:dollars) functions in the official Mootools website.